# How to change format of TextClock in android with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, format

```
<TextClock
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

This is my TextClock in my layout file
I wanted to programmatically change its format from 12 hours to 24 hours

So far I have tried this:

```
var textClock: TextClock = view.findViewById<TextClock>(R.id.textClock)
textClock.format24Hour = "hh:mm:ss a"
```

But nothing seems to be working.
There is a method called `setFormat24Hour(CharSequence format)` in java but in Kotlin I am not able to achieve the desired result.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "but in Kotlin I am not able to achieve the desired result."? Are you trying to say that this works in Java but not Kotlin? This seems near impossible, Kotlin is fully interoperable with Java.

Comment: I mean I cannot use the setFormat24Hour in kotlin. in kotlin there is only things possible
textClock.format12Hour and textClock.format24Hour, which are not changing the format of the clock

Comment: Glad the solution worked, but just for the future, `TextClock.format24Hour` is an alias for the `TextClock.setFormat24Hour` method. They are identical, so there's nothing 'in Java' that you can't call with Kotlin. As far as I'm aware this is called *property access syntax*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock#setFormat24Hour(java.lang.CharSequence)) says, the `setFormat24Hour(CharSequence)` method:

> Specifies the formatting pattern used to display the date and/or time in 24-hour mode.

It doesn't actually change the clock to a 24 hour one. Instead the `TextClock` uses the system default setting to decide which format to use.

However if you really want to enforce the format, you should set the format of the other mode to `null`, which will force it to display how you want.

Comment: Thanks, passing null to the other method worked!